# Pandas get all rows where the values match a specific row

Tags: pandas

So I have this code

```
unique_values = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

for _, row in unique_values.iterrows():
    mask = (df == row).all(axis=1)
    df_subset = df[mask]
```

So the above is supposed to find all the unique rows in the dataframe then find all the rows that match those values in the original dataframe. For whatever reason the above code `df_subset` only returns a 1 row dataframe even if there are multiple rows in the original dataframe that match `row`. How do I get all rows with specific column values that are in a pandas row?

So for example if I have row=[0,01] and a dataframe that looks like [[0,0,1],[2,2,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]] it should return indexes 0,2,3,4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
>>> df[df.eq(row).all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, (m := df.eq(row)), m.all(axis=1)],
              keys=['df', 'mask', 'all'], axis=1)

  df         mask                  all
   0  1  2      0      1      2      0
0  0  0  1   True   True   True   True
1  2  2  0  False  False  False  False
2  0  0  1   True   True   True   True
3  0  0  1   True   True   True   True
4  0  0  1   True   True   True   True
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  2  2  0
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1

>>> row
[0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use isin Pandas method**

```
rows=[0,1]
mask=df.isin(rows)
df_sub=df[mask.all(axis=1)]
print(df_sub.index.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
row = np.array([0,0,1])
np.flatnonzero((row == df.values[:, None]).all(axis = 2)).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for all column unique value

```
df.groupby([{all column}]).apply(lambda x : list(x.index))
```